# Shared VHDX in Hyper-V CSV Not Keeping Data Synced Between VMs

Tags: cluster-computing, hyper-v, iscsi

We are implementing a new clustered environment using 2 Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Hyper-V servers and a SAN using a Dell SCv2020 via iSCSI, and using a shared VHDX file between 2 Windows VMs.  Note that I have also added a shared disk as a VHD Set with the same results.

THE PROBLEM:

When I add a file to the shared drive (e.g. "test.txt"), only the VM that it was added on sees the file.  The other VM does not see the file that I added to the shared drive.
How do I get the data to sync between both VMs using the shared drive?

CONFIG INFO:

iSCSI is working fine and the Cluster is working, with the CSV volumes being presented on both Hyper-V servers fine.

As a proof-of-concept, on each Hyper-V machine, I have a VM named TEST01 and TEST02, respectively.  Both OS VHDX drives are separate.

- In Hyper-V, I added a shared VHDX file to be used as a shared data drive, and it is located in the CSV volume located at C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\TEST-SHARED.vhdx
- I added that shared VHDX to both TEST VMs successfully as a new SCSI drive.
- I ensured that both VMs mounted the shared drive with the same drive letter, "Z:"
- I was able to perform a drive expansion by 5GB without any issues, and both VMs saw the updated size.
- As mentioned above, when adding a file to the shared VHDX from one VM, the other VM does not see it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might try asking this question on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/), which is dedicated to professional server stuff.

Comment: Thanks.  Someone had a similar question there.  It will not work the way I thought it would.

Comment: It does not work that way. See:
https://serverfault.com/questions/665182/file-sharing-using-hyper-v-shared-vhdx